# Entity Framework 5 - DbContext Has Changes?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I'm trying to find a way to determine of any changes have been made to a database context (DbContext).  Note: I'm using Visual Studio 2012 with Entity Framework 5 on a Windows 7, 64-bit box.

Back when I used to use ObjectContext instead of DbContext, I could do something like:

```
public partial class MyObjectContext
{
    public Boolean HasUnsavedChanges()
    {
        return (this.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified | EntityState.Deleted).Any());
    }
}
```

Now that I'm using DbContext, I tried to do this:

```
public partial class MyDbContext
{
    public ObjectContext ObjectContext()
    {
        return (this as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
    }

    public Boolean HasUnsavedChanges()
    {
        return (this.ObjectContext().ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified | EntityState.Deleted).Any());
    }
}
```

The problem that I'm having is that the method "HasUnsavedChanges()" always return "false" even when I know for a fact that the context has been changed.  Does anyone have any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

For EF 5 use `DbContext`'s `ChangeTracker`:

```
 public bool HasUnsavedChanges()
 {
    return this.ChangeTracker.Entries().Any(e => e.State == EntityState.Added
                                              || e.State == EntityState.Modified
                                              || e.State == EntityState.Deleted);
 }
```

For EF 6 use the `ChangeTracker.HasChanges()` method which will also detect changes in many to many relationships:

```
 public bool HasUnsavedChanges()
 {
    return this.ChangeTracker.HasChanges();
 }
```

Comment: Is there any way of doing this that isn't O(N)?

Comment: @DrewNoakes - The MSDN page for DbChangeTracker states, "Note that some types of entity (such as change tracking proxies and entities that derive from EntityObject ) report changes automatically and a call to DetectChanges is not normally needed for these types of entities. Also note that normally DetectChanges is called automatically by many of the methods of DbContext and its related classes such that it is rare that this method will need to be called explicitly" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbchangetracker(v=vs.113).aspx). Perhaps via IL/CLR?

Comment: Adding entities into M:N collections is not detected by this code. (EF 6.1.3)

Comment: hi thx for your answer - what about using ObjectStateManager or is ChangeTracker a better way? chrs mate

Answer (score 38):

I know as you are using **Entity Framework 5**, this answer will not help you, but it may help others.

Starting with **Entity Framework 6** and in **Entity Framework Core** you can check for changes simply by following line of code:

```
context.ChangeTracker.HasChanges()
```