# Detect if an entity framework object has changed

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to check if an entity object has changed (including if any of its children have been modified).
I'm using Entity Framework 4.4

My code basically loads in the object from the DB and applies values to some properties (however they may be the same as the original).

I know I can check `entityObject.EntityState`, but does it update if children have a change, or do I need to loop through all the children in the object?

This is because if it has I need to run a whole bunch of other code (like send an email alert to a user and stuff saying that values have been updated, but I don't want to run that code if they haven't been updated).

Comment: The `EntityState` refers to **that entity** only - not to all its children. If you need to know if the entity or any of its children have been modified, you'll need to traverse the tree of children and check each child entity's `EntityState` property, too

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that, as if I add another table I may forget to traverse that one. Is there a way to get all children so I can write a generic method that would traverse them even if schema changes at later stage?

Comment: Erm, maybe by using a recursion?

Comment: > marked as duplicate by Gert Arnold - That is no use to anyone if you don't link to the duplicate Gert.

Comment: Gert Arnold, you marked this as a duplicate, but it's not.
* this question: is an object changed
* other question: are there any objects changed

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question:
[Entity Framework 5 - DbContext Has Changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012607/entity-framework-5-dbcontext-has-changes)

if you use a dbContext for only this operation you might have your solution.