# how do i check if property actually change before an update

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I am using EF 5 (not 6). I have an object of below class and it is in DB using EF.

```
public class Student
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int Age { get; set; }
  public DateTime DOB { get; set;}
}
```

Later on,

I got request to make an update to same object / record.

But before making update call , i would like to cross compare whether property actually changed because i may get the same record for an update so don't want to make blind update.

```
 var student = _context.Students.select(x =>x.Name == "").first();
 student.name = "";
 student.age = "";
 student.DOB = "";
_context.Entry(student).State = EntityState.Modified;
_context.saveChanges();
```

Does EF gives me some built in way to this?

Or, I need to cross compare each property one by one and decide? I can have 20 properties ...

Any idea please?

Comment: What does _"I may get the same record for an update"_ mean, exactly? Doesn't your record have a primary key?

Comment: having primary key would make what difference to my question? My saved record has primary key. later on someone called the same method by just sending Name, Age and DOB parameters. Now i need to decide whether just make blind update call or at least compare the properties first? unless i am missing something imp about EF

Comment: If you remove the line `_context.Entry(student).State = EntityState.Modified;`, EF will do the check for you.

Comment: The `EntityState.Modified` is useless in your case because the entity your are updating is already tracked by the context - so you can remove it without any harm. EntityStates usually used on detached contexts

Comment: If you want to know what field has been changed and to what value - then you should write you own method for that purpose, EF won`t do it for you.

Comment: What are you trying to prevent? A useless database roundtrip for `UPDATE foo SET bar='baz'` where `bar` already contains `'baz'`?

Comment: I am getting it as DTO so not sure that value will always be same or changed

Answer (score 7):

Starting with EF 6

```
context.ChangeTracker.HasChanges()
```

Please refer to the documentation

> Checks if the DbContext is tracking any new, deleted, or changed entities or relationships that will be sent to the database if SaveChanges is called.

[DBChangeTracker Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbchangetracker(v=vs.113).aspx)

Or you can read from this blog how this method [Secrets of DetectChanges](https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/03/10/secrets-of-detectchanges-part-1-what-does-detectchanges-do/)

**UPDATE:**
For EF 5, there is an alternative

```
return this.ChangeTracker.Entries().Any(e => e.State == EntityState.Added
                                              || e.State == EntityState.Modified
                                              || e.State == EntityState.Deleted);
```

This answer is not mine, I take it from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12012716/4827151) so give credit to the right person.

Comment: unfortunately i am not EF 6 and even not going to EF 6 soon.

Comment: @simbada sorry version was not specified, this is just for reference also

Comment: @simbada If your question is specific to a version then add that important information to your question.

Answer (score 2):

The statement below:

```
_context.Entry(student).State = EntityState.Modified;
_context.saveChanges();
```

Will update all the relevant field of the entity, thus marked as dirty.

On the code behind  it is like this:

```
UPDATE student
SET Value 1 = 'whatever student name is',
    Value 2 = 'whatever student name is'
WHERE Id = 123;
```

If you want to update specific value, please use the

```
_context.Student.Attach(student)
```

Which on the code behind will look like this:

```
    UPDATE student
    SET Value 1 = 'whatever student name is'
WHERE Id = 123;
```

If you want to check if property changed before the update override the equals method of your object and compare the properties you desire:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    return MyProperty == ((MyObject)obj).MyProperty
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Equals` method and the `IEquatable<T>` interface could be used to know if two objects are equal but they won't allow you to know the differences between the objects.